# Overloaded function templates that differ only in their return types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, overload-resolution

It is well known that ordinary functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded in C++.

But this limitation does not hold for overloaded function templates, for example:

```
int f(auto) { return 1; }
auto f(auto) { return 2; }
```

All compilers accept it, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qj73Mzehd

Why does the language make such exception for the templates?

If the return type of the overloaded functions differ, then it will be possible to select one of the functions using the cast to expected function type. Surprisingly, Clang allows one to resolve the ambiguity even if the return type is actually the same, for example:

```
((int(*)(int))f)(3);
```

selects

```
int f(auto) { return 1; }
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/snfvbq1ME

Is Clang wrong here?

Comment: gcc doesn't accept it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j6Enr9h93, i don't think the cast should work in the first place. There are tricks to transform the two `auto` functions into template avoiding clashing (perhaps these are applied by clang and gcc), but still they need disambiguating by other mechanism. I can put the possible template explicit code in an answer if you are curious.

Comment: @Timo - That is immaterial. The bit about **signatures** is important. I wish folks around here could sort the wheat from the chaff on their own. Anyway, I reopened because it's not about **specialization**, but the templates themselves.

Comment: mmm, this has nothing to do with with `auto` arguments. With templates the function definitions work as well https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6dzc65xfa . Still gcc rejects the cast.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah but isn't the signature (including template arguments) the same in both cases? I thought auto return type doesn't contribute as a template parameter.

Comment: @Timo - No, it isn't the same. That's the whole answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so `auto` is the actual return type in the signature? It doesn't get deduced first?

Comment: @Timo - It's deduced when the body is instantiated, for every specialization. Not once for the template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why does the language make such exception for the templates?

You mean this?

> **signature** [**[defns.signature.templ]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.defs#defns.signature.templ)
>
> ⟨function template⟩ name, parameter-type-list, enclosing namespace (if any), return type, template-head, and trailing requires-clause (if any)

Yes, the return type is there. It's what always made possible things like

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type foo(T&);

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type foo(T&);
```

SFINAE is why the return type is included in the signature. Substitution failure is possible in the return type, so it's part of signature comparison. You can still potentially generate two conflicting specializations to overload on (in the general case, not in the example), but the templates would be different.

Comment: Is SFINAE the reason or a side effect? As allowing `template <typename T> T Make();`...

Comment: @Jarod42 - For this specific signature definition? SFINAE I daresay. C++98 didn't have that, it only mentioned specializations.

Comment: I meant the WHY is still a problematic question. That template exception allows several stuff as SFINAE or `std::get<0>(my_tuple)`. And C++98 already allowed both usages and more (except `std::tuple` is not C++98 ^_^, but that form was allowed). (and there were different ways to use SFINAE without that as default argument; in addition the return type SFINAE doesn't work with constructors).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Any "why" question is problematic. The long and short of it is that this definition made its way in along with lots of other work about improving SFINAE. So it's not a long shot to say SFIANE is the motivator.